# Cause of thread dump : Dump Event "systhrow" (00040000) Detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" "Java heap space" received

Tags: java, websphere, hystrix, heap-dump, thread-dump

Heap memory consuming very fastly .From the analysis of heap dump we understood JAXBUtils object is top consumer.Our application uses SOAP XML request and response for third party communication and hystrix using for fault tolerance

We analyzed java core of IBM websphere from that we get to know **hystrix-ANONYMOUS_GROUP** thread (hystrix command group) is in blocked state .
Please see below java stack from java core.

at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/message/databinding/JAXBUtils.getJAXBContext(JAXBUtils.java:364(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/message/databinding/JAXBUtils.getJAXBContext(JAXBUtils.java:245) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/marshaller/factory/MethodMarshallerFactory.isContextPathConstruction(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:220) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/marshaller/factory/MethodMarshallerFactory.isDocLitBareMinimal(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:205) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/marshaller/factory/MethodMarshallerFactory.createDocLitMethodMarshaller(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:129) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/marshaller/factory/MethodMarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:116) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/client/proxy/JAXWSProxyHandler.createRequest(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:528) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/client/proxy/JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:246) 
at org/apache/axis2/jaxws/client/proxy/JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213(Compiled Code))

Top consumer in heap dump is org/apache/axis2/jaxws/message/databinding/JAXBUtils

Please tell me the possible reason for this issue